# Genesis Theme - Modify Query in Featured Post Widget to Exclude Category

Tags: wordpress, genesis

The Genesis theme has a Featured Posts widget that allows you to display a list of posts from a selected category. I'd like to add the capability to exclude posts that are assigned a given category(s) as well.

So, I might select to show posts that have category "Tools", but exclude posts that also have categories "Hammers, Wrenches".

Comment: Please describe your question with code

Comment: There's no code to share in my current position of exploring this problem. I'm looking for insight as to how this might be done.

Comment: You have to edit the widget to query posts based on your needs

Comment: So do I copy the widget code from my parent theme into my child and make the necessary changes? Or is there a way to hook into the query for that widget and modify it?